# How to avoid Meteor Autorun with Meteor.user() inside run each time Meteor.user change

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I am confused because I have an autorun in Meteor-Angular and I need to subcribe each time the variable this.getReactively('perPage') changes, but before I need to verified if Meteor.user() exists, so I need to put it inside of the funtion autorun, but my problem is that this autorun runs each time not just when this.getReactively('perPage') changes but when Meteor. user changes, I dont know if there is a way to avoid that, maybe compare previous value of Meteor.user, I dont know. Someone could help me? thanks

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
        if(this.getReactively('perPage')){
            if(Meteor.user() ){
            console.log(this.getReactively('perPage'));
            Meteor.subscribe('notifications_bell',Meteor.user().notifications_bell,this.getReactively('perPage'));
            }
        }
    }.bind(this));
```

Comment: Why you don't want function to rerun on Meteor.user() change? I can see you are using `Meteor.user().notifications_bell` in subscription so you should rerun subscription when it changes.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Meteor.userId()` instead. That only changes when a user logs in or out. You're probably changing the user object more frequently.

Also you don't need to pass `Meteor.user().notification_bell` to your subscription. You can directly access that on the server inside your publication. That will also be more secure (you should never pass any data to the server that is already available there).